# Proximity Matrix in sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to perform clustering in Python using Random Forests. In the R implementation of Random Forests, there is a flag you can set to get the proximity matrix. I can't seem to find anything similar in the python scikit version of Random Forest. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent calculation for the python version?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We don't implement proximity matrix in Scikit-Learn (yet).

However, this could be done by relying on the `apply` function provided in our implementation of decision trees. That is, for all pairs of samples in your dataset, iterate over the decision trees in the forest (through `forest.estimators_`) and count the number of times they fall in the same leaf, i.e., the number of times `apply` give the same node id for both samples in the pair.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I access the apply function? If I try: i_node = tree.apply(full_data[i]). I get "AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'apply'"

Comment: It looks like this functionality is higher up in sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier. And then I don't need to iterate over all the trees? Is this correct? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.apply Just apply one entry at a time?

Comment: Indeed, sorry, `apply` is directly available in the forest, hence you don't need to iterate over the trees yourself.

Comment: @GillesLouppe thanks! I had a follow up question regarding what the best way to visualize this proximity matrix that I posted in CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409263/how-to-visualize-proximity-score-in-random-forests.

Comment: Ah sorry, never mind, I realized you explain how it was created a bit later in your dissertation.

Answer (score 17):

Based on Gilles Louppe answer I have written a function. I don't know if it is effective, but it works. Best regards.

```
def proximityMatrix(model, X, normalize=True):      

    terminals = model.apply(X)
    nTrees = terminals.shape[1]

    a = terminals[:,0]
    proxMat = 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)

    for i in range(1, nTrees):
        a = terminals[:,i]
        proxMat += 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)

    if normalize:
        proxMat = proxMat / nTrees

    return proxMat   

from sklearn.ensemble import  RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
train = load_breast_cancer()

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, max_features=2, min_samples_leaf=40)
model.fit(train.data, train.target)
proximityMatrix(model, train.data, normalize=True)
## array([[ 1.   ,  0.414,  0.77 , ...,  0.146,  0.79 ,  0.002],
##        [ 0.414,  1.   ,  0.362, ...,  0.334,  0.296,  0.008],
##        [ 0.77 ,  0.362,  1.   , ...,  0.218,  0.856,  0.   ],
##        ..., 
##        [ 0.146,  0.334,  0.218, ...,  1.   ,  0.21 ,  0.028],
##        [ 0.79 ,  0.296,  0.856, ...,  0.21 ,  1.   ,  0.   ],
##        [ 0.002,  0.008,  0.   , ...,  0.028,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing currently implemented for this in python. I took a first try at it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270201/pooling-levels-of-categorical-variables-for-regression-trees/). It would be great if somebody would be interested in adding these methods to scikit.