# Parallelization with multiprocessing, joblib or multiprocess is not working

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, spyder

There is this stackoverflow post that really nicely shows a way to calculate the proximity matrix of a `RandomForestClassifier()`.

[Proximity Matrix in sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703136/proximity-matrix-in-sklearn-ensemble-randomforestclassifier)

Nevertheless the for-loop in that script is quite slow if you have a large dataframe. I tried to parallelize this for-loop, but unsuccesfully. I only get 'None' as an output.

How can I parallelize this for-loop in ***Spyder 4*** running ***Python 3.8.5*** on ***Windows 10***?

```
proxMat = 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)

for i in range(1, nTrees):
      a = terminals[:,i]
      proxMat += 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to perform a reduce operation - so parrallelization is not obvious.
You did not specify how you tried to parallelize the loop.
A simple way to parrallelize :

```py
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

def get_outer(i):
   return np.equal.outer(terminals[:,i],terminals[:,i])

todo = list(range(1, nTrees))
results = pool.map(get_outer, todo)
proxMat = 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)
for res in results:
    proxMat+ = res
```

I'm not sure this one would help, but possibly you'd have less pickling problems :

```py
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

def get_outer(t):
   return np.equal.outer(t,t)

# This part might be costly !
terms = [terminals[:,i] for i in range(1, nTrees)]

results = pool.map(get_outer, terms)
proxMat = 1*np.equal.outer(a, a)
for res in results:
    proxMat+ = res
```

Comment: Hi SergeD,

Thank you for your suggestion, however the results throws an error: 'Can't pickle <function <lambda> : attribute lookup <lambda> on__main__ failed'

Comment: Try declaring the function by another mean (regular function declaration, etc). If you have a well defined function, multiprocessing.pool.map should work. I edited the code.

Comment: There are many discussions it seems on how to pass several arguments to pool.map. Maybe check here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments