# proximity matrix random forest for regression (sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Looking at [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) I cannot see "Python's sklearn" random forest implementation to implement proximity matrices OOTB (e.g. like in R). Maybe I am wrong? If not I take it I have to implement somethig along [those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703136/proximity-matrix-in-sklearn-ensemble-randomforestclassifier)?

Comment: As far as proximity matrices go, there's not really a difference between regression and classification, is there? And so your linked question seems actually a duplicate?

Comment: Is it a duplicte as I ask for the latest state of this? I would also think that the produced proximity matrix depends on the target?

Comment: @BenReiniger does it matter if model is overfitted in the sense that I did not optimise hyperparameters and thus use same dataset to fit random forest and resulting proximity matrix to cluster?